# How to send information from node to angular's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, iframe

I have an angular application running within an iframe of the main page 
(i.e. I'm creating an atlassian confluence add-on). I have Node on my backend. Now, when the user clicks on a link (`https://www.theplace.com/?location=yourlocation`), Node will get that query string (`location=yourlocation`), grab the corresponding information for that page and send that info to the front-end.

But, when Node sends the response with corresponding information that was retrieved from the database with the given query string from the url, how can you use that information to populate the $scope of one of the angular controllers?

It's good to note that the query string is on the parent frame, so angular (within the child iframe) cannnot access the parent's url.

Comment: What you're actually asking is: how can I send data from the parent to a child iframe?

Comment: simply call the node API in the controller and get the response in callback

Comment: @Anzeo visa-versa. get data from the parent to the child

Comment: @maddygoround i could, BUT when i send the request to node, I don't know what to send. That query string from the parent url (`location=yourlocation`) is not visible to the child iframe.

Comment: so you are making a service call in parent html and you want the response in child html right !

Comment: @maddygoround the parent html isnt doing anything. everything is done within the child html. at least, i dont have any controller over the parent html

Comment: i am still confused.then how you are making a service call to nodejs ?

Comment: @maddygoround the service call is done with the child html

Comment: can you put our parent.html and child.html code here

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't really understand why you really need the parent/child construct , you should make your Node.js service return JSON, and use the standard Angular HTTP methods:

See

- [Angular HTTP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)